# ejabberd message level read receipts

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am using ejabberd with Smack for pushing messages from a Java application and then consuming these messages on a website using bosh/strophe. This works great, and now I have to change the way a message is marked as read. Currently any message (new or old using xep-0313, xep-0136) is 'read' as soon as it's delivered. I want to change it to be marked as read only after the user on the website does an action, e.g. checks a checkbox. So, if a user logs into the portal again, he should see the message as unread as long as he hasn't checked the checkbox for that particular message.

I looked into the following modules, but none seem to be doing what the requirement is -

XEP-0333 - Chat Markers – Not on an individual message level.

XEP-0184 - Message Delivery Receipt – specification doesn't seem to distinguish between delivery and display based on any end-client action

Any inputs/suggestions welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Ejabberd does not have any such built in feature. You need to change your logic of sending read receipt. You should send it only if the user clicks on the button.

Comment: thanks @HareKumar. Do I need a particular module (e.g. XEP-0184) and then customize strophe to send the receipts on click? Or is there some other way? I am using mod_offline so I was thinking if there is a way to modify it continue storing the messages till a user event (e.g. a click) on a message.

Comment: Yes, XEP-0184 is required if you wish to send delivery receipt. Not sure what exactly u mean by last line.